# How do I deploy multiple root/intermediate CAs to multiple Java instances across multiple servers?

Tags: ssl, java

I have a number of different servers running different software packages developed by multiple internal teams.  As they're trying to connect their applications through web calls, we're finding that Java doesn't seem to trust the commercial CA we're using (Comodo).  The solution would seem to be to go import the root and intermediate certs into they keystore for each Java instance, but I can't seem to find a good way to automate this.  It seems manual per instance.

Can anyone point me at any method of doing this wholesale?

Comment: on what operating system does these java instances work?

Comment: Mix of Windows and Linux.

Comment: ok, then for windows you should be able to use gpo's to deploy those certificate authorities; for linux, if you use rhel or similar (centos, etc) version 6 or higher you can use the update-ca-trust tool (see man 8 update-ca-trust, tldr; quick help)

Comment: So I think you're missing the point a bit - while the servers can trust those, and I have methods to make the servers trust a CA, Java maintains its own keystore, and there's no method I know of to push that in an automated fashion...

Comment: I just gave you those methods... In RHEL distributions there is the 'shared system certificates' project: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SharedSystemCertificates and oracle java can trust the Windows cert stores. See this blog post for an example: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/01/11/java-webapplication-certificates-and-citrix/

Comment: @natxoasenjo the OS distributions will cover the root cert, but not probably not Comodo's intermediary cert

Comment: people: have you tried? I have, and it works. So please, give it a try just for laughs ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an intermediary certificate rather than a root one.  It's signed by a cert which java will recognise (presumably distributed by your OS vendor), so your java app could just download the required intermediary cert if it's missing.  downloading over http is fine, since you'll validate that the content has been signed by a known root cert.

If you do want to distribute the cert from outside of your app, you want a configuration management tool.  e.g. Puppet, Chef, Ansible and Salt are all popular options.

If this is the only thing you're going to manage, then Ansible is probably going to be the simplest to set up, but I'd recommend you take a bit of time to think about whether you should make a fuller use of configuration management in your environment.

Comment: So my only question here is - yes, I get that I can use Puppet to deploy a keystore at the time of Java deployment, but I'm not sure how I use it to retrofit it on a bunch of Java instances in multiple locations using multiple, already possibly populated, keystores.  That's what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: Right.  Puppet is mostly attractive if you have a broader need which would justify setting up a puppet agent on each target system.  Ansible is a more likely option since it is agent-less, using ssh (linux) or powershell (windows).  You will need to have ssh or powershell enabled on the target systems though.  I think you'd be better off having your software download the cert itself, but that also requires some forethought in order to update your software to have that functionality.  How do you currently handle security updates?

Comment: So we already run Puppet extensively - my question here, I guess, is that Puppet seems more suited to deploying a set keystore upon Java deployment presuming all of my Java deployments are managed/identical (unfortunately currently they are not).  You're suggesting using Ansible similarly to Rundeck or mCollective to run the import commands against multiple servers, I think.  I was hoping there was something that could scan, determine Java installs, deploy the certs, etc.

For what it's worth, we use IEM to patch.  I'd have to write custom fixlets for each Java install.

Comment: No need for ansible if you have puppet, and IMO better to put this logic in your java app. I'd have thought though that you'd use your existing patching mechanism to add logic to your app to make sure it downloaded the appropriate intermediary cert on demand.  Chances are the URL for that intermediary cert is in the cert that uses it.  E.g. look at `openssl x509 -text -in [your.crt] | grep OCSP`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I'm trying to retrofit.  It looks like I'm just flat out of luck.